# file_get_contents() doesn't work because url includes &amp; and %20

Tags: php

I use file_get_contents() to read remote files. It works fine with normal charactered urls, but however, a client has some files which are like

```
http://www.site.org/?m=sp_view_doc&file=publicpolicy/shared%20documents/therapeutic%20discovery%20project%20credit%20general%20guide.pdf
```

and it shows this in source code

```
http://www.site.org/?m=sp_view_doc&amp;file=publicpolicy/shared%20documents/therapeutic%20discovery%20project%20credit%20general%20guide.pdf
```

I have tried urldecode(), but not worked. How can I avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple `str_replace("&amp;","&",$url)` would work just fine.

`%20` is perfectly ok within URLs, since it just stands for a space, so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `html_entity_decode(urldecode($string))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [rawurldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) it will turn the %20s into spaces instead of pluses like urldecode does.